# trying to retrieve a resources but for some reason an error is being thrown

Tags: android, android-layout

I am new to android development. i am following their tutorial at:  [android development](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html#ReadSharedPreference)

Now when i do

```
int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
```

i am getting an error however when i use:

```
int defaultValue = (int)R.string.saved_high_score_default;
```

It works perfectly fine.

here is the error i get:

```
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.fragments/com.example.android.fragments.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040003 type #0x3 is not valid
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4953)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040003 type #0x3 is not valid
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.content.res.Resources.getInteger(Resources.java:838)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at com.example.android.fragments.HeadlinesFragment.onStart(HeadlinesFragment.java:60)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:1332)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:906)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1080)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1062)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:1815)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:518)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5170)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2083)
08-25 07:38:13.228: E/AndroidRuntime(3436):     ... 11 more
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, maybe I'm misunderstanding, but I think that's just a typo in the tutorial.

`getResources().getInteger()` should take a resource value of type `integer`, for example:

```
getResources().getInteger(R.integer.my_int_value_key);
```

Which would be defined in a values XML somewhere like:

```
<integer name="my_int_value_key">100</integer>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a value in values.xml with the name stored in R.string.saved_high_score_default.

That's a bit of an overly complex way to do it in my mind.  I'd be using a java constant for the default (a private final int DEFAULT_VALUE) instead of reading it from xml in most situations.

Comment: If i do not have a value in strings.xml how would `int defaultValue = (int)R.string.saved_high_score_default;` work perfectly fine ?

Comment: There you aren't reading the integer value named "HighScore", you're assigning the value of the resource id of the string holding "HighScore".  Which will be some rather large number.  Their example is really bad.

Comment: You're correct , now that i checked the returned value is some oddly large number. So how am i suppose to retrieve the number there ?

Comment: That value actually doesn't point to a number.  That value points to a string.  Their code then takes the string, looks for it in the xml, and grabs the integer value associated with it.  It's really oddly overengineered.  If you want to make their code work, add the value to your xml like @kcoppock suggested.  If you want to clean it up, just use a java constant.

Comment: Thanks for your help gabe sechan

Answer (score 0):

This line is trying to get an int from a string resource:

```
    int defaultValue = getResources().getInteger(R.string.saved_high_score_default);
```

Try something like:

```
    int defaultValue = Integer.valueOf(getResources().getString(R.string.saved_high_score_default));
```

Comment: Eli, yours seem to work (unless the value is not an integer(in which case there's an error i assume its unable to conver//parse it to int)