# android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #112: Error inflating class com.android.ex.chips.RecipientEditTextView

Tags: android, eclipse

I have cloned the git Calendar project and tried to run on my samsung galaxy S3,
after launching the app on my phone, I tried to create a new event and got the below stack trace.

```
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.calendar.iselection/com.android.calendar.iselection.event.EditEventActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #112: Error inflating class com.android.ex.chips.RecipientEditTextView
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #112: Error inflating class com.android.ex.chips.RecipientEditTextView
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:761)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:855)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:751)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:354)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at com.android.calendar.iselection.event.EditEventFragment.onCreateView(EditEventFragment.java:567)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1699)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1075)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1455)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5381)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2266)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     ... 11 more
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     ... 30 more
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f040000 type #0x3 is not valid
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDimension(Resources.java:1408)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at com.android.ex.chips.RecipientEditTextView.setChipDimensions(RecipientEditTextView.java:751)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     at com.android.ex.chips.RecipientEditTextView.<init>(RecipientEditTextView.java:259)
01-21 14:24:43.754: E/AndroidRuntime(8255):     ... 33 more
```

How do I resolve it?

This is my dimen.xml :

```
<resources>
<dimen name="chip_padding">8dip</dimen>
<dimen name="chip_height">32dip</dimen>
<dimen name="chip_text_size">14sp</dimen>
<dimen name="line_spacing_extra">4dip</dimen>
<integer name="chips_max_lines">-1</integer>
```

and this java class :

```
    private void setChipDimensions(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RecipientEditTextView, 0,
            0);
    Resources r = getContext().getResources();

    mChipBackground = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.RecipientEditTextView_chipBackground);
    if (mChipBackground == null) {
        mChipBackground = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.chip_background);
    }
    mChipBackgroundPressed = a
            .getDrawable(R.styleable.RecipientEditTextView_chipBackgroundPressed);
    if (mChipBackgroundPressed == null) {
        mChipBackgroundPressed = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.chip_background_selected);
    }
    mChipDelete = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.RecipientEditTextView_chipDelete);
    if (mChipDelete == null) {
        mChipDelete = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.chip_delete);
    }
    mChipPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RecipientEditTextView_chipPadding, -1);
    if (mChipPadding == -1) {
        mChipPadding = (int) r.getDimension(R.dimen.chip_padding);
    }
    mAlternatesLayout = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.RecipientEditTextView_chipAlternatesLayout,
            -1);
    if (mAlternatesLayout == -1) {
        mAlternatesLayout = R.layout.chips_alternate_item;
    }

    mDefaultContactPhoto = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(r, R.drawable.ic_contact_picture);

    mMoreItem = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.more_item, null);

    mChipHeight = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RecipientEditTextView_chipHeight, -1);
    if (mChipHeight == -1) {
        mChipHeight = r.getDimension(R.dimen.chip_height);
    }
    mChipFontSize = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RecipientEditTextView_chipFontSize, -1);
    if (mChipFontSize == -1) {
        mChipFontSize = r.getDimension(R.dimen.chip_text_size);
    }
    mInvalidChipBackground = a
            .getDrawable(R.styleable.RecipientEditTextView_invalidChipBackground);
    if (mInvalidChipBackground == null) {
        mInvalidChipBackground = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.chip_background_invalid);
    }
    mLineSpacingExtra =  r.getDimension(R.dimen.line_spacing_extra);
    mMaxLines = r.getInteger(R.integer.chips_max_lines);
    TypedValue tv = new TypedValue();
    if (context.getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, tv, true)) {
        mActionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(tv.data, getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics());
    }
    a.recycle();
}
```

I have laucnh app Calendar in debug mode :

```
       mChipPadding = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RecipientEditTextView_chipPadding, -1);
    if (mChipPadding == -1) {
        mChipPadding = (int) r.getDimension(R.dimen.chip_padding);
    }
```

the value of the R.dimen.chip_padding = 2130968576
is that correct? in the dimen.xml the chip_padding is define to 8dpi( dpi???)

[image]

I have tried replacing the 8dip by 8dp, but havin the same error,
in R.java of com.android.chips i have the reference of chip_padding :

```
public static final class dimen {
public static final int chip_height=0x7f040001;
public static final int chip_padding=0x7f040000;
public static final int chip_text_size=0x7f040002;
public static final int line_spacing_extra=0x7f040003;
}
```

so i do not really understand why it said the it did not found the ID....

Comment: Try clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: I've tried that but still having the error...

Answer (score 1):

You have a **missing dimension ressource**. 
So you should add a res corresponding to the id `0x7f040000` in *dimens.xml*.

You have to find whats the name of the missing dimension by yourself by inspecting your layout, or by adding your layout to the question.

It could be that the ressource is missing from the original project, in this case post an issue to the Github page.

**Edit** : you have to look on the layout where you use `com.android.ex.chips.RecipientEditTextView`

Comment: @Omzo25 you have to edit you question to add the `dimens.xml` AND the layout where you use `RecipientEditTextView`

Comment: I've just added my dimen.xml file, about the layout i'm a bit confused beacuse i am new on android, so i've add the code snippet that call the name specify in dimen.xml

Comment: your layout will be in res/layout and it will be inflated from your activity or fragment. Can you past the full java class ?

Comment: The full java class have more characters than the body can hold, is there any i can send you that file ?

Comment: normaly stackoverflow didn't accept external attachment but if the class is on Github you can past the url ;)

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/ex/+/kitkat-release/chips/src/com/android/ex/chips/RecipientEditTextView.java

Comment: I am trying to send the debug screenshot but i need 10 reputations to do so :),

Comment: try to replace `dip` with `dp`. According to the Stacktrace, one res is wrong type `Resource ID #0x7f040000 type #0x3 is not valid` but I can't help you more you have to find why by yourself.
Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18426101/trying-to-retrieve-a-resources-but-for-some-reason-an-error-is-being-thrown with same issue.

Comment: Hey @Hugo Gresse, i'm still having the error, i tried every fix found on the web but still having that issue... anything that can help me...